# Angular material 6 Tree Structure Editing with CSS Properties

Tags: html, css, angular

I want to change the CSS Properties of the angular material tree structure like
padding of the child element that added after clicking on the button.
But problem is that I am unable to find the files or code of CSS where I can change it.
is there anyone know?
plz help

Comment: you didnt get anything at node_modules/ angular / material for the CSS files?

Comment: I go through with all file in node_modules/angular/material of extension .d files but not properly understand that code and there are no CSS properties listed in that all file.

Comment: and i dont know why people downvoated the question if i have doubt . cant i asked here ?? its a right place to question

Comment: People downvote to questions which are simple and should be part of the study for the tool... it is discouraging, but don't let anyone stop you; try to be thorough an d learn from existing issues on sO

Comment: yup, I agree with your point but this is not the simplest question I spend a whole day searching for the answer and when I unable to find the answer then I raise the issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply `inspact` the element in F12 (develop tool) and see the properties of `material`

[See example in stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-tree-simple-cxnugm?file=app/app.component.html)

**In your own css override this properties or add properties:**

[image]

**In example for this image use in your css file:**

```
.mat-tree-node {
padding:50px;
}
.mat-tree-node button{
padding:10px;
}
```

**Edit to your comment!**

> Set properties only to child

[**Use `:nth-child()`:**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-tree-simple-cxnugm?file=styles.scss)

```
mat-tree-node:nth-child(2) { padding-left: 37px!important; }
```

Comment: ok, I did it.  but how to edit that padding-left  property that applies to the child after clicking on the parent element I wanna reduce that padding-left size of the child element

Comment: see here in style.scss file:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-tree-simple-cxnugm?file=styles.scss

Comment: .mat-tree-node {
    padding-left: 20px!important;
  }

Comment: this add the peeding-left to PARENT ELEMENT  also ...

Comment: `mat-tree-node:nth-child(2) {
  padding-left: 37px!important;
}`

Comment: happy to hep BTW I edited answer